# Can't able to make my home page static in one of the theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have download Illyria theme there I was trying to make my homepage static .i tried making it in by going into setting in reading section n make home page as static ...but it is not working kindly help me out with this problem how to make my home page static

Answer (score 0):

you can make your home page static by selecting a page (which you want to make your home page) from drop down list in Setting > Reading > select A static page then select a page from drop down list and also select your post page from second option.

Comment: please deactivate you all plugins and then try to make static page. may be its because of any outdated plugin or it any pkugin is conflicting with its settings.